# Slow exponential evaluation over lists

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77333/slow-evaluation-of-nintegrate-when-used-as-a-pure-function),which is still unanswered, might be relevant because it involves `NIntegrate` over lists and it also has `Exp`.

In the question linked I encountered slow evaluation of `NIntegrate`. I thought it might be because Mathematica somehow does the calculations slowly over lists and it is not the fault of `NIntegrate` the slow performance, however I am not sure yet. Anyway, I tried to calculate the integral by the simplest method that is boxing the area under integral.
Consider this:

```
<<Developer`
axis = ToPackedArray@Table[1.*i, {i, 0, 10000, 0.01}];
Total[0.01*Exp[-axis]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {10.108011, 1.0050083333194446}

It is really slow compared to Matlab. Then I tried:

```
Exp[-axis]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {8.998900, Null}

and

```
Sin[-axis]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.009001, Null}

It seems exponential on a list is really slow.

Compiling helps a lot:

```
exp = Compile[{{axis, _Real, 1}},

  Apply[Plus, 0.01*Exp[-axis]],
  Parallelization -> True, CompilationTarget -> "C"
  ]

exp[axis] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.062006, 1.0050083333194315}

But still Matlab is ten time faster.

Matlabs code:

```
axis = 0:0.01:10000;
tic
sum(exp(-axis).*0.01)
toc
```

> ans =
>
> 1.0050
>
> Elapsed time is 0.006555 seconds.

Why is Mathematica slow in this case and how can I make it faster?

I think this happens because Mathematica keeps really small numbers:

```
Exp[-1000000.]
```

> 3.296831478*10^-434295

How can I prevent this? Is it related to the issue at all?

### Edit

It seems for Mathematica length isn't important but size does matter!

```
axis2 = Table[Abs@Sin[1.*i], {i, 0, 10000, 0.01}];

Total[0.01*Exp[-axis2]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.015000, 5558.330252144095}

Although the length of the list is the same as before its values are between zero and one and it's faster.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think Packeing will help in this case because Exp breaks this Packing. PackedArrayQ[Exp[-axis]] is False.

Comment: Possibly related: [Exp is slower for some number ranges](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47982/18476)

Comment: Matlab returns `0` for `exp(-1000000.)`.

Comment: Related: ["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24857/how-to-flush-machine-underflows-to-zero-and-prevent-conversion-to-arbitrary-prec/25668#25668).

Comment: @Karsten7 I didn't get the point. Did you mean the implementation of `Exp` in Mathematica is less efficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with an extension to the point raised in your edit.

```
rL = RandomReal[{0.5, 1.5}, 10000];
timings = Table[{10^n, AbsoluteTiming[Exp[-(rL*10^n)]][[1]]}, {n, 0, 5, .01}];
ListLogLinearPlot[{timings, {{746, 0}, {746, 0.05}}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"Scaling", "Time"}, Joined -> {False, True}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}]
```

[image: Plot]

The red vertical line is placed at `n=746`. Matlab returns `0.` for `exp(-n)` if n>=746.

Setting

```
SetSystemOptions["CatchMachineUnderflow" -> False]
```

as shown in [this answer by Oleksandr R.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25668/18476), for which [Michael E2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4999/michael-e2) provided a link in his comment to this question, improves the timings significantly.

[image: Plot2]

*Mathematica* is slower than Matlab, because Matlab uses machine precision whereas in *Mathematica* `Exp` can be evaluated to arbitrary numerical precision.

One can define a numerical version of `Exp` to "make it faster" using

```
nExp = Compile[{{x, _Real, 0}},
        Exp[x], CompilationTarget -> "C", Parallelization -> True, 
        RuntimeAttributes -> Listable, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Now

```
{nExp[-745], nExp[-746]}
```

> `{5.*10^-324, 0.}`

similar to Matlab, the timings are independent of the scaling
[image: numericExp]

and

```
0.01 Total[nExp[-axis]] // Timing
```

> `{0., 1.00501}`

is much faster.

Comment: BTW, `NSum[0.01 Exp[-i], {i, 0., 10000., 0.01}] // Timing` and `Sum[0.01 Exp[-i], {i, 0., 10000., 0.01}, 
  Method -> "PolynomialExponential"] // Timing` are both returning `{0., 1.00501}`.